Here I'm trying to host my react website but during my command prompt type "npm i build", after this it throw a error
enter image description here
here it show error but I can't understand
added 2 packages, and audited 329 packages in 6s
106 packages are looking for funding
run npm fund for details
5 vulnerabilities (1 high, 4 critical)
To address issues that do not require attention, run:
npm audit fix
Some issues need review, and may require choosing
a different dependency.
Run npm audit for details.
I try to install npm i build for host my react project

maybe the command you tried to find is npm run build?

Dependencies cause these errors, and in general, many different situations can provide this.
As a first recommendation, you can update the node version installed in your system. You can quickly switch node versions with nvm. And then, make sure you're using the latest legacy version of React.
As I said, despite these, errors caused by addictions may not be solved. If there is no problem when the project stands up despite these mistakes, the developers usually do not care much about it.
